# call java Controller from angularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller

This is my situation, I have a project in Netbeans 8.2, in the html, here call angularjs, but when need to call java controller from angular we receive a "not found" in chrome debug, in the factory with the $http send the "url", but I dont can to call java controller.

-- This is code html

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
<div data-ng-controller="MyController">
<button data-ng-click="getDataFromServer()">Test Angularjs</button>
</div>
</div>
```

-- This is the code in angularjs (this is a File.js)

```
var app = angular
        .module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])

        .controller('MyController', function ($scope, $service, $http, $resource) {          
            $scope.getDataFromServer = function () {

                $service.JS_STST_GetData();
            }

        })// end controller    
.factory(
        '$service',
        function ($http) {
            return {
                JS_STST_GetData: function (){
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'TestMaping',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }
                    }).then(_success, _error);
                },
```

-- This is the Java Controller Code

```
@Controller
public class VerController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/TestMaping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String TEST(Model model){
        return "Test";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String otroMetodo(Model model){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sending POST request to a controller that only accepts GET requests. That may be the issue.

Comment: Your code ran on my machine with ```GET``` request to pull data from a file. I hope you have defined ```_sucess``` and ```_error``` functions. Assuming everything is Okay with you JS code, I would like you to add a slash at the beginning ```url: '/TestMaping',```

Answer (score 5):

You are making a `POST` call while your controller request mapping is of method type `GET` for url `/TestMaping`. Please correct it & try.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, but not is the solution.

Comment: Try to put a full URL in your controller (loclahost:port...) rather than just /TestMapping

Comment: Thanks, but it´s doesn´t work, this is the message:angular.js:12407 POST http://localhost:8080/EjSpringMVC/TestMaping 404 (Not Found).

I dont know if I need to configured something.

Comment: Just to ensure that the controller is being initialized, please debug on constructor OR print a statement from the constructor of ```VerController ```

Comment: how to define the contructor, because i was based in a example and not remember has a contructor .

Comment: Well, that is something very basic for a Java programmer. Here is one for you:  
 ```public VerController() {
  System.out.println("VerController object instanciated...");
 }```

Comment: I added the code, but i receive the same message when I need to excecute from angularjs to java controller angular

Comment: Did your constructor run?

Comment: Yes, but i was a reading i think is about the structure file in the project, because I saw an example of Spring angular and the structure file is totally different